# Old fan had 2 switches, one for light one for fan. How can I utilize the same setup on a new smart fan setup with remote

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I am replacing an old hunter fan with a new patriot lighting fan.  The old unit functioned off of 2 switches, 1 for the light and 1 for the fan.  I would like to retain the same function for the new fan, however it has a remote that runs everything (no more pull chains). Running into the issue that I can control the fan with the second switch but only when the main switch is on. When I turn it off it drops power to everything.

Below is the wiring schematic provided by the company, however I have two power (black and red) coming from the 2 switches.
[image]

Comment: If you are willing to stuff the remote receiver behind one of the switches, in the wall, instead of in the fan/light box, then you just simply wire accordingly. I did this with my setup at home, and for the fan, I fashioned the remote holder onto the fan switch cover, and use the remote for the fan, and the standard switch below it for the light.

Comment: The two powers for the switches are a three wire set, one is the fan, the other the light, then both return on the same neutral.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is *you can't have it both ways*.

There are 4 things people want to do with a fan/light:

- Turn the light on/off
- Adjust the intensity of the light (a.k.a., dim)
- Turn the fan on/off
- Adjust the speed of the fan

There are three different places these things can be controlled:

- Pull chains - Works well, if inconvenient, for on/off of light and fan. Except that you have to remember which chain is which. Doesn't work as well, if at all, for light intensity (not at all in my limited experience) or fan speed (you have to cycle through the different speeds - e.g., if it is "high, medium, low, off" and you want to switch from high to medium it is one pull, but if you want to switch from medium to high it is 3 pulls).
- Wall switches - Works well for on/off provided you have two separately switched hot wires. Otherwise you end up using a single switch to turn everything on/off and the pull chains as well to adjust speed, and also to (inconveniently) turn the light on because the last time the light was already off when someone flipped the switch off, etc. Meaning you have two separate controls that get very confusing. If you do have the two separate hot wires and separate switches then you can add light intensity control by using a compatible dimmer switch and/or fan speed control by using a compatible switch (which has to be specifically designed for fan motor speed control).
- Remote control - Works really well until you lose or break the remote. A little confusion for new users (including guests) because the wall switch turns everything on/off, or possibly off but not on. So you put a holder on the wall for the remote next to the regular switch and put a piece of tape over the regular switch and use the remote for everything. And everything is fine until you lose the remote. Or someone puts it down and the dog gets ahold of it. Or you're watching TV and a kid has it on the floor and forgets about it and someone steps on it. Etc.

The whole complicated remote receiver installation is simply because it is cheaper for the manufacturer and retailer to have one fan/light with an included, but optional to install, remote control, than to have two separate SKUs of every style/size of fan - one with the remote and one ($10 cheaper, maybe) without. And then have to deal with the people who want to return because "I have two switches I didn't want the remote" and "I thought these things come with everything I need but there's no remote and my regular switches don't have dimming (but the box said dimmable) and speed control (but the box says adjustable speed)". So they put it all in one but *don't* connect the remote at the factory.

Back to the original question. Here is what you do:

- Ignore the remote control transmitter and receiver.
- Connect all light "hot" wires to one incoming switch wire (e.g., black)
- Connect the fan "hot" wire to the other incoming switch wire (e.g., red)
- Connect all white wires (neutral) together.
- Connect all ground wires together.

If you replace the light switch with a dimmer then you can adjust the light intensity.

If you replace the fan switch with a fan speed control then you can adjust the fan speed (highly recommended).

However, this particular fan/light presents a couple of complications. The diagram references additional wires for:

- Uplight vs. downlight - If you connect them all to one switch then all the lights will turn on/off/dim together. That may be OK or it may not.
- Fan *direction* control (orange wire). This could be a real problem. It is not clear what direction the fan will turn if you don't connect this wire. It is not clear how you can reverse direction if you don't use the remote control.

So it appears the remote control for this particular model is a bit more complex than the standard "just replace two switches and dim and speed". (Specific model # may provide insight.)